# Why does a headphone attenuator need separate resistance for each side instead of a shared resistor for both?

Tags: resistors

I have a [Shure headphone attenuator](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00029U0X6) and opening it up it looks like there are separate pins on the pot for the left and right speakers (the pot has 5 pins, which I believe are left in/out, right in/out, and ground), like this:

(I have no experience creating schematics and I'm not sure what I should be using to represent the input or how to represent the 5 pin pot, but I've tried to convey what I'm talking about)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7Dw8c.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Why is the resistance applied separately to the left/right sides, instead of using a pot with 3 pins and applying between both speakers and the ground, like this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNRMKu.png)</sup>

My reason for wanting to understand this is that I want to modify a 4-pole TRRS headphone extender to create a fixed-resistance attenuator compatible with headphones with a remote/microphone and I'd like to understan the circuit on my existing attenuator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do as you say there will be interaction between the left and right channels.

Any signal in one channel will result in a voltage across the resistor that will then excite the other channel.  Stereo systems go to great lengths to minimize crosstalk between channels.  Ideally there should be less than 1% of the signal in the left channel getting into the right channel and right to left (this is about -40dB).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that general idea makes sense. Could you explain a bit more about why there will be interaction  with the resistor in that location, but no interaction if the two speakers both go to the same ground without a resistor in that location?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

It's easier to understand if you only drive one speaker at a time. Let's assume the speaker amplifier's output resistances are zero (the ideal case). Then the ground resistance (aka the common impedance) (R2) and the 8 ohm speaker (speakers aren't really 8 ohm resistors, but close enough for this purpose) will be a parallel resistor equal to something under 8 ohms. That 8 ohms forms a nearly equal voltage divider with the left speaker so that half of the drive voltage for the left speaker appears across the right speaker, causing very bad crosstalk. As you lower the value of R2, the overall parallel combination is reduced and as it approaches zero, so does the amount of crosstalk. In your screenshot, the impedances are not common to the speakers individual current flows, so they don't cause crosstalk.

This is similar to why star grounding (or ground planes) is used in power supplies: Minimizing the common impedance in the current return path.

Comment: To add to my comment, *if* the speakers did have completely separate return currents that were star grounded at one point, then you could add the pots on either leg, since there would be no common impedance to worry about.

Comment: Hi mhz, good answer giving a worked example. You don't need to comment on your own answer, you can just edit it until it's perfect. Comments are more for a Q&A discussion about details.

Answer (score 2):

It should be left signal in, right signal in. (That's 2 pins)
Then there would be 2 pots (ganged). 
So the left pot wiper and right pot wiper to keep the signals separated and keep stereo signals. (That's 2 more pins) 
Then everything shares a ground. (The fifth pin)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fz0KQz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So the Actual pot has Left and Right IN, Shared GND and Left and Right OUTs